# External hard drive disappears even during file operation

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd, disconnect

I have a Western Digital Green 2TB SATA disk in an ICY BOX IB-368STU3-B box connected via USB 3.0.

At a certain moment, the disk is not available anymore (and the blue LED on the back of the box shut down).

See dmesg log:

```
[418367.616545] usb 7-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[418367.633699] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0731
[418367.633709] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[418367.633715] usb 7-2: Product: USB 3.0 Mass Storage Device
[418367.633720] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: Raid Sonic
[418367.633725] usb 7-2: SerialNumber: 0000000000000806
[418372.632296] usb 7-2: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
[418376.219833] usb-storage 7-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[418376.220738] scsi2 : usb-storage 7-2:1.0
[418376.222967] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[418377.221322] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD20 EZRX-00D8PB0     80.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[418377.222015] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[418377.222420] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029164 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[418377.223166] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[418377.223175] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[418377.223924] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[418377.223933] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[418377.226889] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[418377.226904] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[418377.255267]  sdc: sdc1
[418377.258061] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[418377.258072] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[418377.258080] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[418378.570903] EXT4-fs (sdc1): recovery complete
[418378.571188] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[427069.908051] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command
[427070.165440] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Stopped the command ring failed, maybe the host is dead
[427070.165440] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Abort command ring failed
[427082.535178] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[427082.535232] usb 6-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[427082.536024] [sched_delayed] sched: RT throttling activated
[427082.536122] usb 7-2: USB disconnect, device number 0
[427082.940059] usb 7-2: device not accepting address 2, error -22
[427082.940172] sd 2:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

I exchanged it with another box (same but a new one), same effect.

I changed the DD in it with a Seagate Green 2TB, same effect.

I tested on 2 USB3 ports, 2 USB2 ports, another laptop, Ubuntu (the distro currently running my laptops), Debian stable (to test another kernel) and Sysrescue, same effect.

The first time, it stopped while I was doing an `rsync` on it, so it was in activity (I copied 1TB of data on it) and all of a sudden, I received errors `Input/Output errors` and /dev/sdc1 not existing anymore.

Any idea what it could be?

Thanks for the help!

Best regards,

Raph

Answer (score 0):

Well I would have said that it looks like a bad usb controller based on those messages, but if you have tested it in multiple controllers that rules that out.  The other two possibilities are the cable, and the enclosure.  Try another cable, and if you can, remove the drive from the usb enclosure, and connect it directly to a sata port.

Comment: I already used the DD in another enclosure and it works correctly.
I tried a completely new enclosure so, new controller, new cable new everything and same.
I tried the new one on USB2 ports on my laptop and it worked.
I then tried it on a front USB2 of my Zotak and it woke up \o/ (took long but ok)
I will try again on USB3 ports, maybe it's linked with a recent kernel upgrade.